# Generating XML file from text input

Tags: c++, xml

I am hoping the code is readable as is. I can probably just print the XML using streams but I have other reasons for using the library.

Please offer any inputs on how to improve program design/structure.

The header file

```
#ifndef GEN_XML
#define GEN_XML

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

typedef std::string stringType;
typedef std::vector<stringType> stringVector;
typedef std::vector<int> integerVector;

class gen_xml
{
private:
    int previousTime;
    int tempTime;
public:
    stringVector text_file;
    integerVector time_ms;
    stringVector text_info;
public:
    gen_xml():previousTime(1),tempTime(2) {};

    virtual int validate(int argc,char* argv[]);

    virtual void showInput(int argc,char* argv[]);

    virtual bool validateFileExtention(stringType fname,stringType ext);

    virtual int getAbsoluteTime(stringType value);

    virtual void getData(char* argv[]);

    virtual stringType toString(int num);

    virtual void generateXML(stringVector text_file,integerVector time_ms,char* FileName);

};

#endif  // GEN_XML
```

The CPP file

```
#include "tinyxml.h"
#include "tinystr.h"
#include "gen_xml.h"
using namespace std;


int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    gen_xml req;
    if(req.validate(argc,argv))
    {
        req.getData(argv);
        req.generateXML(req.text_info,req.time_ms,argv[2]);
    }
    cout<<"Done"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
void gen_xml::generateXML(stringVector text_file,integerVector time_ms,char* FileName)
{
    TiXmlDeclaration* declaration = new TiXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "no");//Create DTD
    TiXmlDocument* doc = new TiXmlDocument;
    doc->LinkEndChild(declaration);

    TiXmlElement* msg;

    TiXmlElement * root = new TiXmlElement( "tags" );
    doc->LinkEndChild( root );
    for(int i=0; i<(int)text_file.size(); i++)
    {
        TiXmlElement * msgs = new TiXmlElement( "metatag" );
        msgs->SetAttribute("event", "onCuePoint");
        msgs->SetAttribute("overwrite", "true");
        root->LinkEndChild( msgs );

        msg = new TiXmlElement( "name" );

        msg->LinkEndChild( new TiXmlText("CuePoint"+toString(i) ));
        msgs->LinkEndChild( msg );

        msg = new TiXmlElement( "timestamp" );
        msg->LinkEndChild( new TiXmlText(toString((int)time_ms.at(i))));
        msgs->LinkEndChild( msg );

        msg= new TiXmlElement( "parameters" );
        msgs->LinkEndChild(  msg );
        TiXmlElement * _params = new TiXmlElement( "textinfo" );
        _params->LinkEndChild(new TiXmlText( text_info.at(i)));
        msg->LinkEndChild( _params );

        msg= new TiXmlElement( "type" );
        msg->LinkEndChild( new TiXmlText("navigation"));
        msgs->LinkEndChild(  msg );
    }


    doc->SaveFile( FileName );
}
string gen_xml::toString(int num)
{
    stringstream abc;
    string value;
    abc<<num;
    value=abc.str();
    return value;
}

int gen_xml::validate(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    fstream filestr;
    string temp;
    bool result;
    if(argc>3)
    {
        cerr<<"Input Arguments Exceeded"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if(validateFileExtention(argv[1],".txt")&&validateFileExtention(argv[2],".xml"))
    {
        filestr.open(argv[1]);

        if (filestr.is_open())
        {
            filestr.close();
            result=true;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error opening file";
            result=false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
void gen_xml::getData(char* argv[])
{
    fstream filestr;
    string temp;
    filestr.open(argv[1]);
    while( getline( filestr, temp ))
    {
        text_file.push_back( temp );
    }
    //cout<<(int)text_file.at(0).size()<<endl;
    //getAbsoluteTime(text_file.at(0).substr(0,12));

    for(int i=0; i<(int)text_file.size(); i++)
    {
        time_ms.push_back(getAbsoluteTime(text_file.at(i).substr(0,12)));
        temp=text_file.at(i).substr(13,(int)text_file.at(i).size()-14);
        text_info.push_back(temp);
    }
    filestr.close();
}
int gen_xml::getAbsoluteTime(string value)
{
    int hours,minutes,milliseconds;
    int absTime;

    (stringstream)value.substr(3,2)>>hours;
    (stringstream)value.substr(6,2)>>minutes;
    (stringstream)value.substr(9,3)>>milliseconds;
    absTime=60*1000*(hours*60+minutes)+  milliseconds;

    //-- stupid fix for a tool... dont ask why
    tempTime=absTime/1000;
    if(previousTime==tempTime)
    {
        absTime=(tempTime+1)*1000;
    }
    previousTime=tempTime;
    //--
    return absTime;
}
bool gen_xml::validateFileExtention(string name,string ext)
{
    string str (name);
    string str2 (ext);

    size_t found;
    bool res;
    int num_periods = count(name.begin(), name.end(), '.');
    found=str.find(str2);
    if ((found!=string::npos)&&(num_periods==1))
    {
        //cout << "file extention"<<str2<<"found at: " <<int(found) << endl;
        res=true;
    }
    else
    {
        // cout<<"file name incorrect"<<endl;
        res=false;
    }
    return res;
}
void gen_xml::showInput(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    cout<<"argc = "<<argc<<"\t";
    for (int i = 0; i<argc; i++)
    {
        cout<<"argv["<<i<<"] = "<< argv[i]<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would remove the validate method and do some modifications:

About `validate`:

- Check `argc` and `argv` outside the class, just provide the `filename` to the `getData` method.
- You also need to check when `argc` is less than 2, the user may forget to supply the `filename`.
- Opening the file in the validate method and closing it again does not guarantee that it will be still available when you call `getData`, so it is better to open the file only there and handle any errors there.

About `getData`:

- I would rename it to `loadData`.
- For each line loaded you insert a value in time_ms and text_info vectors, call `reserve` before the loop to pre-allocate the needed memory.
- No need to call close on the stream, it will close when its scopes end.

About `validateFileExtention`:

- Use `rfind` instead of `find` and just grab the last "." from the string.
- I would instead create a function to copy the `fileExtension` and check both extensions at once, instead of finding the extension each time.
- I would also not even bother about file extension at all.  I would just let the parser validate it.

About `generateXML`:

- Memory leak: you never delete doc.  Also, if you need it just inside the method, why you use dynamic memory? Just create it on stack.
- Also, check if tinyxml deletes everything that you insert on the document.  If not, you will have to handle this too.

Answer (score 3):

**Header file:**

- Since your variables and functions are in camelCase, your own types, especially `gen_xml`, should be in PascalCase.  It shouldn't be easy to mix up all of these based on their naming conventions.
- If you aren't using a particular library in a header file, don't include it.  Header files should include as few things as possible because anything including *those* header files will also be exposed to those libraries.  If any libraries are just needed in the implementation file, then keep them there.

  You're only using `<string>` and `<vector>` in the header file, so move the rest of the libraries to the implementation file.
- The `typedef`s in the header file don't seem too useful, and they don't really save any keystrokes.  If a type is not very long and you cannot give it a shorter (and distinctive) name, then you don't need to use a `typedef`.
- You shouldn't have any `public` data members in a `class`.  All such data members should be `private`.  If you *must* allow them to be changed outside the class after object-construction), then have setters for any individual ones.
- I don't think any of these functions need to be `virtual`.  There's no inheritance or polymorphism being used in this program.
- `showInput()` should be `const` since it's not modifying any data members.

**Implementation file:**

- The final output in `main()` doesn't look necessary.  If you're executing this on the command line, you'll already receive a prompt for the next command.  Plus, it's a little misleading if the file failed to open in the first place.
- `validate()` isn't a very descriptive name as it doesn't specify *what* it's validating.

  It appears to be checking two different things: the number of command line arguments and the file extensions.  You should probably have `main()` validate the former and `validate()` the latter, then terminate if any of them fails.  You should also rename `validate()` to something more descriptive, such as `validateFilename()`.
- `showInput()` should be displaying data members, not command line arguments.  Otherwise, it has no business being a member function.
- This cast to `int` is useless:

  > ```
  > for(int i=0; i<(int)text_file.size(); i++)
  > ```

  The function `size()` already returns an `std::size_type`, which is an integer type.  You don't necessarily need to loop towards an `int` value; any integer type will do.

  Moreover, don't use C-style casting in C++ unless it's absolutely necessary.  For such casts, use the C++-style cast `static_cast<>()`.

  ```
  static_cast<SomeType>(someVariable);
  ```
- `getAbsoluteTime()`'s argument, `value`, should probably be passed by `const&` as it isn't being modified within the function.
- If you have C++11, use [`std::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) instead of your own `toString()` function.